# Reuse clip of a sequence as a new sequence in Kdenlive?

Tags: kdenlive, clipping

I have the following use case: I have two videos from different sources (two different cameras) observing the same event. These two obviously do not start at the same absolute time point, so one of them has to be offset in time relative to the other so both video streams appear in sync.

For this, in Kdenlive, I'd import the two videos as clips in the project bin; and then I'd create a new sequence in the project bin, and place and offset/align the two videos in the sequence. In order to see both videos at the same time, I'd probably have to setup a "picture-in-picture" as in https://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual/Tutorials/Split_Screen_How_To ; and that means that the video tracks within my sequence would look like in the screenshot of that tutorial:

[image: kdenlive tracks]

... except I'd have only two tracks, and one of them would be offset at the start.

So here is the problem: let's say, from two video clip tracks synchronized like this in a sequence, I'd like to cut a clip of the sequence, let's say between 31m:10s:10f to 32m:02s:05f - that in itself is trivial and not a problem. But then, I'd like to rearrange the tracks inside this cut clip of a sequence (so I change the final output of the effects) - *without* changing the original sequence! (so it remains as a master record of the time offset required to sync the two original long video files).

Right now, in `kdenlive-23.04.0-x86_64.AppImage`, if you cut a clip in the middle of a sequence, and then double-click that click to edit it, you're just taken to the original sequence (and as mentioned, I would not like to change it in any way).

What I would like, then, is that when I've cut a clip from a sequence, to have an extra (say) right-click menu, "recreate clip sequence" or something - so that once chosen, a *new* sequence gets created, which contains *only* the cut regions of interest (and correctly offset, as in master sequence), of the original long video files! Then I could rearrange tracks and change effects in this sequence, without changing the original sequence.

Is there any way to achieve this in kdenlive?